# Display list of friends using same in uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-fql

i'm struggling to get this done. I 've made a FBRequest to see who (in my facebook friends) have installed my app.

Here is my code

```
-(void)viewDidload
{


    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {}

         NSString* fql =
         @"SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user=true AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";

         [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                                      parameters:@{ @"q" : fql}
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                   if(error) {
                                       // NSLog(@"Problem");
                                   }
                                   FBRequest *fql = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"fql"];
                                   [fql.parameters setObject:@"SELECT uid,name,is_app_user FROM user WHERE is_app_user AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())" forKey:@"q"];

                                   [fql startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                     id result,
                                                                     NSError *error) {
                                       if (result) {
                                           //NSLog(@"result:%@", result);

                                           //ON PARSE LE RESULT

                                           NSArray *arrayRsult = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                                           NSMutableArray *ins = (NSMutableArray *) [arrayRsult valueForKey:@"is_app_user"];
                                           NSMutableArray *ids = (NSMutableArray *) [arrayRsult valueForKey:@"uid"];
                                           NSMutableArray *names = (NSMutableArray *) [arrayRsult valueForKey:@"name"];

                                           NSMutableArray *recentFriends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                                           NSMutableArray *idFriends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                                           NSMutableArray *nameFriends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


                                           // ON A LE NOMBRE D'USER

                                           for (NSDictionary *d in ins)
                                           {
                                               [recentFriends addObject:d];
                                               [recentFriends removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]];



                                           }

                                           // ON A LES IDS


                                           for (NSDictionary *e in ids)
                                           {
                                               [idFriends addObject:e];



                                           }
                                           // ON A LES NOMS

                                           for (NSDictionary *e in names)
                                           {
                                               [nameFriends addObject:e];



                                           }

                                           NSUInteger arrayLength = [recentFriends count];

                                           NSLog(@"ids are : %@ ",idFriends);
                                           NSLog(@"names are %@",nameFriends );

                                           NSLog(@"there are %i", arrayLength);


                                           data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameFriends, nil];
                                           displayData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:data];

                                       }

                                       else {


                                           NSLog(@"problem , bullshit");}
                                   }];
                               }
          ];}];

    data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameFriends, nil];
    displayData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:data];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                             reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];





    cell.textLabel.text = [displayData  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {

    return [displayData count];

   }
```

In the console I have the id , the number of persons who have the app and the name of them.
And now, I want to display the result of the NameFriends MutableArray in a tableView.

The data I want to show doesnt appear when I write the NSLogs outside the facebook requests.. they seem to be null.

It's the last step to end this part of the project and sadly i can't do this by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to set the value of an instance variable within a block, you have to declare it as:

```
__block data;
__block displayData;
```

Since it's not shown in your code, I'm assuming that you're declaring those variables in your interface.

Also, I'm not sure why you have this at the end of the `viewDidLoad` method outside of the block since it essentially does nothing and should be removed:

```
data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameFriends, nil];
displayData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:data];
```

More info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html

Comment: Thanks ! And I forgot the     [self->tableView reloadData];

Comment: @RaphMaz Glad to help.  If this solved your problem, please hit the checkmark next to my answer to close out the question.